# How to connect to Oracle database in Python with cx_Oracle

Tags: python, cx-oracle, tns

My company has an internal Oracle database that I can connect to using Toad for Oracle just fine.

[image]

However when I try to find any info on myDB in my TNSNAMES.ora file there isn't anything there.

When I try to put this information into a connection string, it just fails.  Not sure what I am missing:

```
 con = cx_Oracle.connect('mySchema/myPass/myDB')
```

Here is the error I get:

```
DatabaseError: ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
```

When I run TNSPING myDB I get this:
'Used LDAP adapter to resolve the alias'

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you want is this:

```
con = cx_Oracle.connect('mySchema/myPass@myDB')
```

Note the use of the @ symbol instead of a second /!